# java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, treemap

I receive the following error when attempting to run my java program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (java.util.TreeMap and java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1569)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.addEntryToEmptyMap(TreeMap.java:776)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:785)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:534)
    at exportsParser.exportsMap(exportsParser.java:53)
    at exportsParser.main(exportsParser.java:28)
```

The applicable code:

```java
import edu.duke.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class exportsParser{

    void println(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    /* The rather involved pattern used to match CSV's consists of three
     * alternations: the first matches aquoted field, the second unquoted,
     * the third a null field.
     */
    private final static Pattern csv_pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+?)\",?|([^,]+),?|,");

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        //println(csv_pattern);
        exportsParser parser = new exportsParser();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./exports_small.csv"));
        parser.exportsMap(reader);
    }
    public TreeMap<String, TreeMap<TreeMap<String,String> ,TreeMap<String, String>>> exportsMap(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException{

        if(reader.readLine() == null) return null;

        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<TreeMap<String,String>, TreeMap<String,String>>> exportsTable = new TreeMap<>();
        TreeMap<String, String> products = new TreeMap<>();
        TreeMap<String, String> value = new TreeMap<>();
        TreeMap<TreeMap<String,String>,TreeMap<String,String>> exportsData = new TreeMap<>();

        int countryIndex = 0;

        ArrayList<String> exportsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;

        try{
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                exportsList = parse(line);

                String countryName = exportsList.get(0);
                products.put("items", exportsList.get(1));
                value.put("total", exportsList.get(2));
                println(products);
                println(value);
                exportsData.put(products, value);
                println(exportsData);

    //              exportsTable.put(countryName,exportsData);
                println(exportsTable);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        reader.close();
        return exportsTable;
    }

    /* Parse one line.
     * @return List of Strings, minus their double quotes
     */
    public ArrayList<String> parse(String line) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher mat = csv_pattern.matcher(line);
        // For each field
        while (mat.find()) {
            String match = mat.group();
            if (match == null)
                break;
            if (match.endsWith(",")) {  // trim trailing ,
                match = match.substring(0, match.length() - 1);
            }
            /*if (match.startsWith("\"")) { // assume also ends with
              match = match.substring(1, match.length() - 1);
              }*/
            if (match.length() == 0)
                match = null;
            list.add(match);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

To clarify, the issue arises when attempting to put the TreeMap data of products and value in exportsData. Same is applicable when attempting to add exportsData to the exportsTable correlating its key (Country) to the exportsData (Value). I understand what the errors means, I just have no idea as to how to fix it. Additionally libraries are not allowed (Purpose is to understand the flow of input data into "rows/columns" and experiment with Trees, HashMaps, etc)

Additionally, I cannot use a database for this as this is a requirement to manually do this. However what is not a requirement is using TreeMaps of course. We are allowed to experiment with the various Collection classes.

I have spent a while trying to get this to work but I have run out of thoughts and forum pages to read now. Eventually, this would be ideal to make it cater towards larger CSV files of unknown columns. However, for the practice run, we have been given the information before hand, hence the indexing in the code above.

CSV data:

```
Country,Exports,Value (dollars)
Germany,"motor vehicles, machinery, chemicals","$1,547,000,000,000"
Macedonia,"tobacco, textiles","$3,421,000,000"
Madagascar,"coffee, vanilla, shellfish","$864,800,000"
Malawi,"tea, sugar, cotton, coffee","$1,332,000,000"
Malaysia,"semiconductors, wood","$231,300,000,000"
Namibia,"diamonds, copper, gold, zinc, lead","$4,597,000,000"
Peru,"copper, gold, lead, zinc, tin,  coffee","$36,430,000,000"
Rwanda,"coffee, tea, hides, tin ore","$720,000,000"
South Africa,"gold, diamonds, platinum","$97,900,000,000"
United States,"corn, computers, automobiles, medicines","$1,610,000,000,000"
```

This is my first time using the above so it is prone to beginner errors.

Comment: TreeMap inherently sorts its contents according to some specified sorting order. Given your keys are themselves also TreeMaps and TreeMaps have no intrinsically defined sorting order, you get this error. I think you're confused and not interested in TreeMap at all. If you want to maintain the same order as how you read it (same as the input file), you want `LinkedHashMap` instead. Most of all, you want to make a new class with fields `String country; List<String> exports; long value;`, and use that instead. Java is nominal. Use java the way it wants to be used.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for. Will take a look at LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

Check [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). To cite - `The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.` Natural ordering of keys means key must implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Your keys are of type `TreeMap`, which does not have natural ordering - it does not implement `Comparable`. Naturally this leads to `ClassCastException`.

If you really must use TreeMap as key for your TreeMap, you must provide a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to TreeMap constructor:

```
Comparator<TreeMap<String,String>> comparator = implement it;
TreeMap<TreeMap<String,String>,TreeMap<String,String>> exportsData = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

Seeing that your data is coming from a csv file, i would suggest to parse it to some custom class. It would be much more readable, and it will be easier to implement `Comparable`, or `Comparator` if needed.

**Edit:** You don't actually need 2 maps - for exports and value, it complicates thing more that needed. Those can be put in a single map. Keys are values from the first line in csv(or other keys, as in your case) and values are corresponding values from the parsed line. So you have:

```
Map<String, String> lineData;
```

Country may also be part of this map(if you need it). Normally it's this map, which will be rerpesented by your custom class, but it looks like your task is to work with collections, so i won't delve into that.

Since you want to map country names to data, now you need another map - keys will be string(country name) and values the map containing line data from above.

All of that can be stored in a list(you can store anything in a list). I'm leaving to you figuring out the exact way to implement it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I don't have to use TreeMap. However it seemed the only one out of the various HashMap, TreeSet, etc that seemed to come close to what I needed. I will take a look at rzwitserloot suggestion about LinkedHashMap, have not read up on that, Will definitely take a look at your link though. Thanks!

Comment: @BobbyBrown I was focusing on TreeMap because it is somewhat trickier to get the hang of, compared to the rest(or least it was for me). Even if it is not the tool for your case, definitely try my last suggestion, parse the lines into custom objects, instead of maps, it's easier to work like that, it's the intended way.

Comment: Definitely will. I was just trying to see if I could keep it all in one script as it is such a small project if you actually had to look at it but I will stick to OOP standards. Thanks dude!

Comment: I was curious if there was a type of list where I could add the treemaps (product and values) to instead of using a comparator as from what I have read bout comparators. I am not trying to compare any objects (at least not intentionally). I have created the custom class but still am a little uncertain about the comparator side. Is there perhaps an alternative as the products and values are not meant to be key value pairs themselves but rather the value with the country being the key itself ultimately. Essentially just bridging the part between products and value together

Comment: in some type of data storage that can accept two values in the same row but remain separate objects would be ideal if that makes sense? Off the top of my head I cannot think of anything without going into nested arrays and what not but that defeats the whole purpose of what the project is about.

Comment: @BobbyBrown Check edit.

Comment: okay awesome. I will definitely take a look at that method. I did not like the flow of my original method and just realised I created a class for the wrong map. Did it specifically for the products and value maps. Thank you!

Comment: You just made me realise how to grab the key names from the data headings using index numbers. lol, simpler than I thought thanks.